# Formula to Remove Repeated Words in a Cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have created a formula to join together text from different cells in Google Sheets.  The problem is that every now and then some of those cells contain the same word which ends up in the joined text.

For example, instead of saying "Large Blue T-Shirt" it will say "Large Large Blue T-Shirt" or "Large Blue Blue T-Shirt", etc.  [this is just an illustrative example].

I have looked, but so far I cannot find a formula to remove repeated words in a line of text.  Does such a formula exist?  If so, what is that formula and how would I use it?

If not, then are there other formulas that I can use to get the desired result?  Again, what are those formulas and how would I use them?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use split and unique, but that would remove all duplicate words so "The cat sat on the mat" would be "The cat sat on mat" - not sure if that would be OK. In other words, do you just want to change consecutive identical words to a single word?

Comment: It would be more efficient (and get you help faster) if you could share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it)—something which already contains at least 10 or 15 rows of realistic sample data. Be sure, in sharing such a link, that you set the link's Share permissions (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that those here can test within the spreadsheet and leave solutions on the spreadsheet (presumable on separate sheets/tabs). Also, please indicate the maximum number of space-separated words per cell of raw data.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I'll add that I believe this can be accomplished with one formula that can detect and remove all repeats per cell, whether the repeated words are side by side or separated by other words. I will be happy to look further into that if a link to an accessible sheet is shared within a reasonable time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something with a helper column `B`:

```
=index(flatten(split(filter(A1:A&"⮐",A1:A<>"")," ")))
```

[image]

```
=index(trim(flatten(split(trim(query(if(B1:B={B2:B;""},,B1:B),"",9^9)),"⮐"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the question isn't tagged as such, maybe a script is the way to go:

```
function removeDups(inString) {
  var arr;
  var outString;
  arr=inString.split(" ");;
  outString= arr[0];
  for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
  {
    if (arr[i]!=arr[i-1]) outString=outString+" "+arr[i];
  }
  return outString;
}
```